# Is it a sin for a human to kill innocent Rakshasas, Asuras, Pisachas, or Nagas?

Tags: sin, rakshasa

It is a sin for a human to kill other humans, animals, etc. But what about celestial beings?

Is it a sin for a human to kill innocent Rakshasas, Asuras, Pisachas, and Nagas? Like can humans commit genocide on them without sinning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a sin for a human to kill Rakshasas, Asuras, Pisachas, or Nagas?

**Yes, it is sinful.**

From the *[Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01184.htm)* on Rishi Parashara's genocide of the Rakshasas:

> “There is no obstruction, I hope, to this sacrifice of thine, O child!
>   Takest thou any pleasure, O child, in this slaughter of even all those
>   innocent Rakshasas that know nothing of thy father's death. It
>   behoveth thee not to destroy any creatures thus. This, O child, is not
>   the occupation of a Brahmana devoted to asceticism. Peace is the
>   highest virtue. Therefore, O Parasara, establish thou peace. **How hast
>   thou, O Parasara, being so superior, engaged thyself in such a sinful
>   practice?** It behoveth not thee to transgress against Saktri himself
>   who was well-acquainted with all rules of morality. It behoveth not
>   thee to extirpate any creatures. O descendant of Vasishtha's race,
>   that which befell thy father was brought about by his own curse. It
>   was for his own fault that Saktri was taken hence unto heaven. O Muni,
>   no Rakshasa was capable of devouring Saktri; he himself provided for
>   his own death. And, O Parasara, Viswamitra was only a blind instrument
>   in that matter. Both Saktri and Kalmashapada, having ascended to
>   heaven are enjoying great happiness. And, the other sons also of the
>   great Rishi Vasishtha who were younger than Saktri, are even now
>   enjoying themselves with the celestials. And, O child, O offspring of
>   Vasishtha's son, thou hast also been, in this sacrifice, only an
>   instrument in the destruction of these innocent Rakshasas. O, blest be
>   thou! Abandon this sacrifice of thine. Let it come to an end.“

Comment: Your are right. Rakshasas, Asuras, Pisachas, and Nagas are creatures just like us. Unfortunately they are compared to demons of other religions.

Comment: @Lokesh That's because they are demons. They are evil.